# as3 centering object

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

Ok, so I've got the following code structure:

```
var environment:AvEnvironment = new AvEnvironment(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);   
addChild(environment);      
environment.addChild(new Player());
environment.addChild(new Terrain());
```

the `player` class passes information on its `x` and `y` to the `environment` class so that the `environment` class will center on the player object. As `terrain` is also a child of the parent, the `terrain` class will also be centered. However, I do not want this to be the case: I want the terrain class to be at the top left of the parent (`environment`) when the game is created.

This is the code I am trying to implement in the terrain class:

```
if(parent)
            {
                var ev:AvEnvironment = AvEnvironment(parent);

                this.x = -ev.x
                this.y = -ev.y

            }
```

However, this does not work in the constructor method as parent returns `null` and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking your Terrain gets initialized, calling your code above, before it gets a parent (addChild()). You can try the following in your Terrain class:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, doDNATest); //Place this in your Terrain() constructor

function doDNATest(evt:Event) {
  //By the time this event is called you should know who the father is
  //since this is called once Terrain is on it's parent's (environment) display list
      if(this.parent)
      {
          var ev:AvEnvironment = AvEnvironment(this.parent);
          this.x = -ev.x
          this.y = -ev.y
      }
}
```

Comment: awesome that worked, however this is not actually really aligning the terrain, in fact its didn't change anything.  when I trace -ev.x and -ev.y I get 0,0. If I was to create a Event listener with the exact same code for a ENTER_FRAME, it would work, except it wouldn't move the graphic.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't entirely clear on that part of the question. So you do not want the Terrain at (0,0)? One thing to check is to make sure the Terrain's movie clip contents are all in the positive X and Y. In other words make sure the Terrain's reference point is at (0,0) and not something like (-400,-300). So is it currently appearing to be centered? Does that help, or am I still not grasping the issue?